# help Environment titlepage undefined. \begin{titlepage} Environment figure undefined. \begin{figure}

Tags: pdftex

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{upg}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\huge{UNIVERSIDAD POLITÉCNICA DE JUVENTINO ROSAS}\\

\vspace{1.0cm}

\large{\textbf{Proyecto Integrador}}
\large{\textbf{Special Health}}
\vspace{0.5cm}



{ \large \bfseries ``Creación de una aplicación para niños autistas"  \\[0.4cm] }


\vspace{1.0cm}


\emph{Presenta:}\\
\\Jairo \textsc{Franco Garduño}
\\Samuel \textsc{Palacios Muñoz}
\\Antonio Ulises \textsc{Paloalto Sierra}
\\Jose Manuel \textsc{Morales Velez}
\\Juan Pablo \textsc{Mendoza Escamilla}


\emph{Asesores:} \\
M.c  Victor Hugo Mancilla García 

\vspace{0.7cm}

\noindent{Santa Cruz de Juventino Rosas, Gto. 16 de Octubre de 2018.}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Hi, we are missing information from your code. Please make your code a full minimal working example (MWE starting by `\documentclass{}` and ending in `\end{document}`) in order to be possible for us to help you.

Comment: Can you correct me

Comment: You have shown us the title page, but you haven't shown us the code that comes before this.  What package or class are you wanting to use to define the title page environment?

Comment: Never use a `figure` environment on a titlepage. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: note that `\huge` and other size commands do not take an argument `\huge{UN...}` is wrong and will make all of the following text huge not just the text in `{...}` It is impossible to answer your main question as you have given no information, all we know is that you are using a document class that does not define titlepage, but you have given no indication which document class that is.